graphql subscription withFilter: variables is empty
I have a graphql subscription that works perfectly well. Now, I would like to add a filter:
commentAdded : {
        subscribe: () => ({
            [Symbol.asyncIterator]:  withFilter(
                (_, args) => pubsub.asyncIterator('EVENT_COMMENTADDED'),
                (payload, variables, context, info) => {
                    return payload.comment.userid === variables.userid
                }
              )
            }
        ),
    },

the variable "args" is empty.
Also: the variable "variables" is also empty !
Same for "context" and "info"
I use Apollo server with:
subscription CommentAdded($userid: String) {
  commentAdded(userid: $userid) {
    userid
    comment
  }
}

I cannot catch the userid in the subscription !!!
I try to catch the parameter (variables) to create the filter.

Hi, did you ever manage to resolve this? I have the exact same problem.

no solution yet...
